# In visual studio code how do I run the same python conda environment in a different folder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

In visual studio code how do I run the same python conda environment in a different folder, assuuming this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ==> `Python:Select Interpreter`

[image]

Select the interpreter for the working environment. The lower right corner of VSCODE will display the interpreter version of the current selection.

[image]

You can choose to use the Conda environment interpreter in different working areas.

You can also add the following settings to setin

```json
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path/to/python.exe",
```